# Fully custom social media share links and share count

Tags: javascript, php, share-button

I want to produce something like this on my site (without plugins)

```
<ul>
    <li class="count">1,034 shares</li>
    <li class="twitter"><a href="...">Twitter</li>
    <li class="facebook"><a href="...">Facebook</li>->
    <li class="google"><a href="...">Google+</li>
</ul>
```

*In the end it will be a little more jazzed up than that.*

So, I’m looking for ways to hand-code all the parts in PHP/Javascript.

- Retrieve individual share counts and add them
- Assemble the right format for the share links

The developer pages for Google, Facebook and Twitter only really help with the standard share link buttons. What I want is FULL control over the link and count number.

Basically, I want them to be available to me in PHP as individual variables.